# how to change method in c# with combobox

Tags: c#

i want to change print template in Windows Forms application
how to change method in c# with combobox
here is my code

```
     private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            PrintDocument document = new PrintDocument();
            document.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(comboBox1.Text);

            document.Print();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
        }
    } 

//Other methods I have to call

private void LabelPrint1(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev){}
private void LabelPrint2(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev){}
private void LabelPrint3(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev){}
```

this is combobox section

```
// comboBox1
        // 
        this.comboBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
        "LabelPrint1",
        "LabelPrint2",
        "LabelPrint3"});
        this.comboBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(806, 627);
        this.comboBox1.Name = "comboBox1";
        this.comboBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 28);
        this.comboBox1.TabIndex = 47;
        this.comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
        //
```

Eroor :
CS0149  Method name expected

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.printpage?view=net-5.0 the PrintPage handler expects an actual method name matching the expected arguments rather than a string i.e.  PrintPageEventHandler document.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(LabelPrint1 );

Comment: After typing `document.PrintPage +=` you can Tab, Enter and VS writes the (empty) event handler for you. It should have a signature like `private static void Document_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)`.

Comment: `document.PrintPage += Document_PrintPage;` then inside this handler, you can reference `comboBox1.Text`. But `(string)comboBox1.SelectedItem` is probably more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just provide the name of the method as string (as you saw). You can `switch` on the name and select the correct method, or first build a dictionary (name -> method), then select from it.

something like:

```
switch (comboBox1.Text)
{
    case "LabelPrint1": 
       document.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(LabelPrint1);
       break;
    // etc for other values

    default:
       throw new InvalidOperationException("Unsupported print handler");
}
```

or something like this on startup:

```
var handlers = new Dictionary<string, PrintPageEventHandler>
   {
      {"LabelPrint1", new PrintPageEventHandler(LabelPrint1)},
      // etc
   };
```

and later

```
  if (handlers.ContainsKey(comboBox1.Text))
  {
     document.PrintPage += handlers[comboBox1.Text];
  }
  // else handle error
```